# Need to pass and use id and parameters from a web service between all components (Angular 4)

Tags: angular, web-services, typescript, parameter-passing, angular2-routing

I'm working in a project related to schools management, now i have 2 web services, one which holds the basic info about school, the second which contains the school divisions, grades, classes and subjects.

The divisions web service is connected to the ID of the selected school so i must pass the ID from school list component to divisions Component and to divisions web service, then to fetch the division data regarding the selected school ID, i tried to do it with the route but it didn't work, i still have to specify which ID i need to display its data, but i need it to work dynamically when i click on any school, without setting it in the NG onInit.

You can see the project from the link below and tell me what do i have to edit in order to pass the school id parameter and use it to fetch its data in division component or any component i want.

I'm still fresh in Angular so try to be as simple and as helpful as you can.

[This is the project link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vduzzk) on Stackblitz

Click on sign in without entering user name or password, click on any school, click on divisions, this is where the issue is, divisions component.

You can find the school service inside business-services

If anything is not clear, just ask.

Also check the router module to see if i'm writing correctly.

Only the school with the ID of 76 has data, rest are still empty.

[Link](https://crm.easyschools.org/api/en/getschools/getSchools) to school list API

Divisions API but you need to send ID parameter in order to fetch data (which is 76 that has data)

[Link](https://crm.easyschools.org/api/en/admin/grades/division) to divisions API

Answer (score 0):

I would store the ID in the service. You can then also call the service in the other component

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environment/environment'
import { SchoolsModel } from '../models/school-model';

@Injectable()
export class SchoolsService {
constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
  }



//You can use Getter and Setter to get your selected School in other 
//components 
 protected  _selectedSchool:SchoolsModel;

  get selectedSchool(): SchoolsModel {
    return this._selectedSchool;
  }
  set selectedSchool(value: SchoolsModel) {
    this._selectedSchool = value;
  }




  public getSchoolList(): any {
    const apiUrl: string = environment.apiBaseUrl +     '/api/en/getschools/getSchools';
    // debugger;
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return this.http.get(apiUrl)
        .subscribe(respose => {
          console.log(respose.data);
      return resolve(respose.data);
    }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      return reject(err);
    });
});
return promise;
  }


  public getSchoolDetail(schoolId: number): any {
const apiUrl: string = environment.apiBaseUrl + '/api/en/getschools/getSchools';
// debugger;
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  return this.http.get(apiUrl)
    .subscribe(respose => {
    this._selectedSchool = respose.data.find(x => x.id == schoolId);

      // debugger;


      return resolve(this._selectedSchool);
    }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      return reject(err);
    });
});
return promise;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what i'm trying to figure out how to store the id and call it in another component

Comment: I have revised my answer

Comment: ok pardon my question but i still dont know how to call it in the division component, i did the getter and sitter but what next?

Comment: This is easy, you have already injected it through the constructor, next you can use it as follows                                                                                               
 let id = this.schoolService.selectedSchool.id

Comment: For you it's easy, i'm still fresh and confused, anyway, thx.

Comment: Try it, and if you've got any more questions, get it out of here.Don't worry, over time it makes more sense

Comment: i did it, i put the selectedSchoolId inside the route and it pulled it, it's just confusing coz it's my first time, thank you martinz, do u mind if i got stuck in the future to ask you? like whatsapp or facebook? i'd understand if you said no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165218/discussion-between-martinzyk-and-mohamed-wahshey).